# JMeter: java.net.URISyntaxException: Malformed escape pair at index

Tags: java, excel, url, jmeter, encode

I was recoding a scenario in JMeter where user searches for record, once the result is listed, clicks on Excel icon to download the result in .xls but below error is displaying while I click on "Excel" icon while recording.

```html
java.net.URISyntaxException: Malformed escape pair at index 336: https://mylink.myURL.com/Change/ExportHandler?objChanger=ANK,All%20Products,A,Jan-2015,Jan-2016,Country,India,,,1&tableName=datatable-example5&iSortCol_0=2&sSortDir_0=desc&aoColumns=Name,Salesa,Salesb,Share,&Header=Name,ABC%20FM%20Gross%20Sales%20(lakhs),Industry%20Gross%20Sales%20(lakhs),share%20share%20(%),
 at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URI$Parser.scanEscape(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URI$Parser.scan(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URL.toURI(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:286)
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:240)
```

Solution on google was to replace % with 25 in URL, can somene please help me in this as in how can I encode the url.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

JMeter provides [__urlEncode()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) function which is designed to escape special characters which are not allowed in URLs.

You can use [Function Helper Dialog](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) available from Menu -> Options to ensure correct syntax is being used

[image: Function Helper Dialog]

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series for comprehensive information on this and other useful JMeter functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String escapedUrl = url.replaceAll("(?i)%(?![\\da-f]{2})", "%25");
```

Comment: Where can I mention this?